# Analytical formula for the variance of ARMA(2,1) model

Tags: time-series, variance, arma

I'm looking for methods to derive an analytical formula for the variance of an ARMA(2,1) model.

Given $$(1-\phi_1B-\phi_2B^2)Z_t=(1-\theta_1B)a_t, $$

I've tried the usual "trick" $$\text{Var}[Z_t]=\text{E}[Z_t(\phi_1Z_{t-1}+\phi_2Z_{t-2} + a_t - \theta_1a_{t-1})], $$
which naturally gives me a relationship between the variance and the covariances $$\text{Var}[Z_t]=\gamma_0 \sim \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \text{const.}$$

I've tried solving this recursive relationship for $\gamma_0$ by generalizing the relationship to e.g. $$\gamma_k \sim \gamma_{k+1} + \gamma_{k+2} + \text{const.},$$
and writing out formulas for $k=\pm1$. But this introduces another unknown covariance $\gamma_3$.

I've also tried to expand $Z_t$ down to a known time value, say $t_0$. But this approach creates a messy formula, which I'm not able to evaluate for the variance.

Are there any other approaches that results in an analytical formula for the variance of an ARMA(2,1) model?

Comment: Is this self-study? If so, please add the tag and read its wiki.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you are trying to find the unconditional variance of the process?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68644/autocovariance-of-an-arma2-1-process-derivation-of-analytical-model-for-ga/68655#68655). If that's not the answer to your question, please give details on your question.

Comment: See also [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97274/variance-of-arma2-1).

Comment: @javlacalle Yes, I was able to figure it out from the first answer you linked. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? What is the solution? Thank you